# How to get parameterized query?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand, parameterized-query

I try to get parameterized query without executing.

```
string query="SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE [ID]=@id";
```

So, i create SqlCommand:

```
int id=10;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
```

How to get parameterized query without it executed- want to get just string like :

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=10"
```

EDIT: i use TFS 2012 and i have to use TFS-based classes to work with it:

```
  Query qry1 = new Query(wis, query, null, false);
  ICancelableAsyncResult car1 = qry1.BeginQuery();
  WorkItemCollection items1 = qry1.EndQuery(car1);
```

So, i like to set a parameterized query into Query class.

Comment: why do you need that?

Comment: @IVAAAN123 he might have to create the report.. or want for logging purpose.. so try to focus on question as its valid one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i would say --

Parameterized query do substitution of pamater just prior to executing the SQL query in Database to make it sure it removes the possibility of Sql injection.  So directly you can not get the FullSql command.. but if you want just for logging or anything else.. like report and all.. using the below snippet to get the full correct command..

```
Logger.Verbose(cmd.CommandText.Replace("@id", id.ToString()));
```

**Update**

oh so  you want to set the sql query in TFS Query class.. better to create the string concatenation query then pass that.. actually Parameterized query doesn't provide a way to get the full prepared SQL Query. use the string concatenation way..! thats the possible and approachable way for this problem..!!

Comment: EDIT: i use TFS 2012 and i have to use TFS-based classes to work with it:

  Query qry1 = new Query(wis, query, null, false);
  ICancelableAsyncResult car1 = qry1.BeginQuery();
  WorkItemCollection items1 = qry1.EndQuery(car1);
So, i like to set a parameterized query into Query class.

Comment: Scarma : so, can i use a string like this: 
string query=@"SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [Something] = '"+Name+'";?
And then- Query qry1=new Query(...,query,..,..); And then execute it?